# How do I install quick.db? (again)

Tags: node.js, discord.js, quick.db

I tried installing quick.db but it doesn't work, I've added Python to the path but all I get is this [error](https://hastebin.com/usayabewot.coffeescript).

I've tried `npm i -g windows-build-tools` and installed it but it still doesn't seem to work.
I've tried this as well: `npm i --global windows-build-tools --vs2015`

Comment: Do you have `node-gyp` installed? Try running `npm view node-gyp version` to see.

Comment: I runned it, here's what it showed:
```7.1.0```

Comment: are you on windows? @ZED

Comment: @BijinAbraham, Yes

Comment: @ZED are you trying to install quick.db in a particular folder?

Comment: @BijinAbraham, No, but I am trying to install it to the node_modules file

Comment: @ZED did you try updating node to latest

Comment: As Bijin suggested, I recommend updating to a newer node version or reinstalling node entirely. Making sure of course to remove the old version before doing so.

Comment: I haven't tried that, I'll download it

Answer (score 0):

Update the `NodeJs` to the latest version.

A fresh install of the newer version is recommended.

Comment: I've downloaded the latest node.js but it doesn't seem to work, it requires higher windows, I'm only at windows 7